# Клавиатура меняет размер контента

Tags: java, android, клавиатура

У меня есть фрагмент, в котором хочу чтобы клавиатура была поверх всего контента и не ресайзила страницу.

В `onCreateView()`:

```
 activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

В XML для полей ввода, установил тот же параметр. Эффекта никакого.
В манифесте для активити ничего про поведение клавиатуры не написано.

Может ли быть, что вся проблема из за того, что в разметке сплошные `FrameLayout`'ы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я для такой задачи в прописываю в AndroidManifest.xml для активити

```
<activity
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden">
</activity>
```

Comment: Сработало, конечно. Но что будет если мне нужна будет другая логика поведения в очередном фрагменте, относящемуся к этой активити?

Comment: Можно программно показывать или скрывать клавиатуру

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard Здесь данный вопрос хорошо описан